# Simple interpreter incorrectly parses file

Tags: lua, interpreter

Yesterday I've wrote interpreter for my new programming language, and I've put it on Github. Before this i made some simple tests and it seemed to work but now when i wanted to write some examples - it didn't work at all! I was really surprised, how did I get that output. For simple programs like this:

```
string Hello World!
locate 0
puts
```

It worked really well, displaying output 'Hello World!'. More complicated program looked like this:

```
ADD 49
PUTCH
SUB 1
PUTCH
MUL 2
ADD 1
PUTCH
SUB 1
DIV 2
PUTCH
LOCATE 2
PUTD
LOCATE 0
SETV 10
PUTCH
SETV 0
LOCATE 0
STRING Hello World
LOCATE 0
PUTS
SETV 10
UNTILZERO
{
SUB 1
}
IFCC 10 == 10 {
LOCATE 0
SETV 0
STRING Ok!
LOCATE 0
PUTS
}
```

*To understand this you need just some knowledge of Lua, C and Assembly.*

How to run code above: ./lua start.lua test.txt -gencode
Output:

```
}UTSTE 0k! 10 {rld
local tape = {}
local pointer = 0
}UTSTE 0k! 10 {rldpe[pointer] + 49
```

*(I don't understand any part of this invaild output)*

So actually my code looks like this:

```
--[[
  ____            _        __            _      _  _   
 |  _ \          (_)      / _|          | |   _| || |_ 
 | |_) |_ __ __ _ _ _ __ | |_ _   _  ___| | _|_  __  _|
 |  _ <| '__/ _` | | '_ \|  _| | | |/ __| |/ /_| || |_ 
 | |_) | | | (_| | | | | | | | |_| | (__|   <|_  __  _|
 |____/|_|  \__,_|_|_| |_|_|  \__,_|\___|_|\_\ |_||_| 
 Brainfuck# v 1.0. Copyright (C) by Krzysztof Szewczyk.
 For more information check CONTRIB.MD and LICENSE.
 Code is licensed under GPLv3.
--]]

output = "local tape = {}\nlocal pointer = 0\n" --We will use Lua 'eval'-like function.
brackets = 0

-- Parse command with parameters 'params', and parameter number
-- 'paramno'.
function parse(command,params,paramno)
    if command == nil or params == nil or paramno == nil then return end

    local cmd = string.upper(command)

    if cmd == ";" then end

    if cmd == "ADD" then
        local amount = params[1]
        output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] + " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "SUB" then
        local amount = params[1]
        output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] - " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "MUL" then
        local amount = params[1]
        output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] * " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "DIV" then
        local amount = params[1]
        if amount == 0 then
            print("[JIT] - Divide-by-zero error.")
        end
        output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] / " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "ADDP" then
        local amount = params[1]
        output = output .. "pointer = pointer + " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "SUBP" then
        local amount = params[1]
        output = output .. "pointer = pointer - " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "MULP" then
        local amount = params[1]
        output = output .. "pointer = pointer * " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "DIVP" then
        local amount = params[1]
        if amount == 0 then
            print("[JIT] - Divide-by-zero error.")
        end
        output = output .. "pointer = pointer / " .. amount .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "LOCATE" then
        local pos = params[1]
        output = output .. "pointer = " .. pos .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "SETV" then
        local val = params[1]
        output = output .. "tape[pointer] = " .. val .. "\n"
    end

    if cmd == "STRING" then
        local str = params[1]
        for i = 1, #str do
            local c = str:sub(i,i)
            output = output .. "tape[pointer] = string.byte(\"" .. c .. "\")\n"
            output = output .. "pointer = pointer + 1\n"
        end
        output = output .. "tape[pointer] = 0\n" --Remember to add null terminator (this can overwrite some of
                                                 --your crap stored in tape, so please have this in mind).
        output = output .. "pointer = pointer + 1\n"
    end

    if cmd == "PUTCH" then
        --Simply, no arguments
        output = output .. "io.write(string.char(tape[pointer]))\n"
    end

    if cmd == "PUTD" then
        --Simply, no arguments                                                                                            ^
        output = output .. "io.write(tape[pointer])\n" --Just print integer (as integer, not character, for character see |)
    end

    if cmd == "PUTS" then
        output = output .. "lastpntr=0\nwhile true do\nif tape[pointer] == 0 then break end\nio.write(string.char(tape[pointer]))\npointer = pointer + 1\nend\npointer=lastpntr\n" --I belive it's too complicated
                                                                                                                                                                                 --But it works.
    end

    if cmd == "GETCH" then
        output = output .. "tape[pointer] = io.read()\n" --HACK: Any raw input is not possible in multiplatform way.
    end

    if cmd == "UNTILZERO" then
        output = output .. "while tape[pointer]\n"
    end

    if cmd == "{" then
        output = output .. "do\n"
        brackets = brackets + 1;
    end

    if cmd == "}" then
        output = output .. "end\n"
        brackets = brackets - 1;
    end

    if cmd == "IUNTIL" then
        local type = params[1]
        local value = params[2]
        output = output .. "while tape[pointer] " .. type .. value .. "\n"
        brackets = brackets - 1;
    end

    if cmd == "TUNTIL" then
        local type = params[1]
        local value = params[2]
        output = output .. "while tape[pointer] " .. type .. "tape[" .. value .. "]" .. "\n"
        brackets = brackets - 1;
    end

    if cmd == "IFCC" then
        local val1 = params[1];
        local comp = params[2];
        local val2 = params[3];
        if params[4] == "{" then
            output = output .. "if " .. val1 .. comp .. val2 .. " then\n"
        else
            print("[JIT]: IFCC needs starting bracket at 4th argument. Please pass it and don't forget to close it.")
        end
    end
    if cmd == "IFCT" then
        local val1 = params[1];
        local comp = params[2];
        local val2 = params[3];
        if params[4] == "{" then
            output = output .. "if " .. val1 .. comp .. "tape[" .. val2 .. "] then\n"
        else
            print("[JIT]: IFCC needs starting bracket at 4th argument. Please pass it and don't forget to close it.")
        end
    end

    if cmd == "IFTT" then
        local val1 = params[1];
        local comp = params[2];
        local val2 = params[3];
        if params[4] == "{" then
            output = output .. "if tape[" .. val1 .. "]" .. comp .. "tape[" .. val2 .. "] then\n"
        else
            print("[JIT]: IFCC needs starting bracket at 4th argument. Please pass it and don't forget to close it.")
        end
    end

end

-- Function to split strings. Any questions?
function string:split( inSplitPattern, outResults )
  if not outResults then
    outResults = { }
  end
  local theStart = 1
  local theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
  while theSplitStart do
    table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart, theSplitStart-1 ) )
    theStart = theSplitEnd + 1
    theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = string.find( self, inSplitPattern, theStart )
  end
  table.insert( outResults, string.sub( self, theStart ) )
  return outResults
end

-- I create new function to ensure that variables
-- won't escape local context.
function main(filename,gencodeswitch)
    local input = io.open(filename, "r")
    if input then
        --No error found while opening file
        while true do
            --First, read line.
            local line = input:read()
            --Now, let's check is it nil.
            --If so, we can break out of this loop.
            if line == nil then break end
            --Else, we need to parse this instruction.
            --So break it into main command and it's params.
            local space = string.find(line, " ") --Find first space occurence (to divide
                                                 --command from it's arguments).
            local params = string.sub(line, space+1) -- To get params just split string.
            local command = string.sub(line, 0, space-1) -- To get command without trailing space.
            --Actually, this space will get removed.

            local paramTable = params:split(",")
            local paramAmount = 0

            -- HACK: Looks like ineffective solution, but who cares?
            for i = 1, #paramTable do
                paramAmount = paramAmount + 1;
            end

            print ("line:" .. line)

            parse(command,paramTable,paramAmount)
        end
        --Done parsing. Generate code
        if brackets ~= 0 then print("[JIT] Unbalanced brackets.") os.exit() end
        if gencodeswitch == "-gencode" then print(output) end
        --loadstring(output)()
    else
        --Oops, an error occured. Couldn't open file.
        print("[JIT]: Please pass vaild filename.")
        os.exit() --Bye, see ya later
    end
end

if arg[1] == nil then
    --User didn't pass any arguments.
    print("Brainfuck# v 1.0")
    print("Ussage:")
    print(".\lua start.lua <input> [-print]")
    print("Where:")
    print(".\lua - lua executable")
    print("start.lua - main module name");
    print("<input> - input filename (non-optional!)")
    print("[-print] - Optional, print source before execution.")
    os.exit();
else
    --User passed an argument
    main(arg[1],arg[2])
end
```

I can't find any errors but there must be a mistake. 
If you want to see repo, [here it is](https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/BrainfuckSharp), but it doesn't contain
anything except license, readme, build and test scripts.
I've put some comments to make understanding this broken code
and trying to fixing it easier.

Can anyone point me out where have I made a mistake?

Comment: The idiomatic way for this in Lua is to define a table whose keys are the commands and whose values are functions that execute each command. This drastically simplifies the code, avoiding the chain of ifs.

Comment: I've thought about it before but I rejected it because I've made a program before like you say and it was really hard to maintain (no one wanted to revise so long code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the liberty to completely revise your code as I saw too many problems with it.  (It didn't even compile as you posted it.)  I guess you're new to programming. Anyway, there is still much more work needed but I'll leave the rest of it for you.  However, it does seem to work now for your example input at least.

I saved your example program as sample.bf and with the command
`brainfuck#.lua sample.bf -gencode | lua` got `Hello World!` as output.  Which is correct, as far as I can tell.

```
--[[
  ____            _        __            _      _  _
|  _ \          (_)      / _|          | |   _| || |_
| |_) |_ __ __ _ _ _ __ | |_ _   _  ___| | _|_  __  _|
|  _ <| '__/ _` | | '_ \|  _| | | |/ __| |/ /_| || |_
| |_) | | | (_| | | | | | | | |_| | (__|   <|_  __  _|
|____/|_|  \__,_|_|_| |_|_|  \__,_|\___|_|\_\ |_||_|
Brainfuck# v 1.0. Copyright (C) by Krzysztof Szewczyk.
For more information check CONTRIB.MD and LICENSE.
Code is licensed under GPLv3.
--]]

output = [[
local tape = {}
local pointer = 0
]] --We will use Lua 'eval'-like function.
brackets = 0

-- Parse command with parameters 'params', and parameter number 'paramno'.
function parse(cmd,params,paramno)
  if cmd == nil or params == nil or paramno == nil then return end
  cmd = cmd:upper()

  local amount

  if cmd == ";" then
  elseif cmd == "ADD" then
    amount = params[1]
    output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] + " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "SUB" then
    amount = params[1]
    output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] - " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "MUL" then
    amount = params[1]
    output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] * " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "DIV" then
    amount = params[1]
    if amount == 0 then
      print("[JIT] - Divide-by-zero error.")
    end
    output = output .. "tape[pointer] = tape[pointer] / " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "ADDP" then
    amount = params[1]
    output = output .. "pointer = pointer + " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "SUBP" then
    amount = params[1]
    output = output .. "pointer = pointer - " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "MULP" then
    amount = params[1]
    output = output .. "pointer = pointer * " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "DIVP" then
    amount = params[1]
    if amount == 0 then
      print("[JIT] - Divide-by-zero error.")
    end
    output = output .. "pointer = pointer / " .. amount .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "LOCATE" then
    local pos = params[1]
    output = output .. "pointer = " .. pos .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "SETV" then
    local val = params[1]
    output = output .. "tape[pointer] = " .. val .. "\n"
  elseif cmd == "STRING" then
    local s = params[1]
    for i = 1, #s do
      local c = s:sub(i,i)
      output = output .. "tape[pointer] = string.byte(\"" .. c .. "\")\n"
      output = output .. "pointer = pointer + 1\n"
    end
    output = output .. "tape[pointer] = 0\n"
    --Remember to add null terminator (this can overwrite some of your crap
    --stored on tape, so please have this in mind).
    output = output .. "pointer = pointer + 1\n"
  elseif cmd == "PUTCH" then --Simply, no arguments
    output = output .. "io.write(string.char(tape[pointer]))\n"
  elseif cmd == "PUTD" then --Simply, no arguments                                                                                            ^
    output = output .. "io.write(tape[pointer])\n" --Just print integer (as integer, not character, for character see |)
  elseif cmd == "PUTS" then
    output = output .. [[
lastpntr=0
while true do
  if tape[pointer] == 0 then break end
  io.write(string.char(tape[pointer]))
  pointer = pointer + 1
end
pointer=lastpntr
]] --I believe it's too complicated but it works.
  elseif cmd == "GETCH" then
    output = output .. "tape[pointer] = io.read()\n" --HACK: Any raw input is not possible in multiplatform way.
  elseif cmd == "UNTILZERO" then
    output = output .. "while tape[pointer]\n"
  elseif cmd == "{" then
    output = output .. "do\n"
    brackets = brackets + 1
  elseif cmd == "}" then
    output = output .. "end\n"
    brackets = brackets - 1
  elseif cmd == "IUNTIL" then
    local type = params[1]
    local value = params[2]
    output = output .. "while tape[pointer] " .. type .. value .. "\n"
    brackets = brackets - 1
  elseif cmd == "TUNTIL" then
    local type = params[1]
    local value = params[2]
    output = output .. "while tape[pointer] " .. type .. "tape[" .. value .. "]" .. "\n"
    brackets = brackets - 1
  elseif cmd == "IFCC" then
    local val1 = params[1]
    local comp = params[2]
    local val2 = params[3]
    if params[4] == "{" then
      output = output .. "if " .. val1 .. comp .. val2 .. " then\n"
    else
      print("[JIT]: IFCC needs starting bracket at 4th argument. Please pass it and don't forget to close it.")
    end
  elseif cmd == "IFCT" then
    local val1 = params[1]
    local comp = params[2]
    local val2 = params[3]
    if params[4] == "{" then
      output = output .. "if " .. val1 .. comp .. "tape[" .. val2 .. "] then\n"
    else
      print("[JIT]: IFCC needs starting bracket at 4th argument. Please pass it and don't forget to close it.")
    end
  elseif cmd == "IFTT" then
    local val1 = params[1]
    local comp = params[2]
    local val2 = params[3]
    if params[4] == "{" then
      output = output .. "if tape[" .. val1 .. "]" .. comp .. "tape[" .. val2 .. "] then\n"
    else
      print("[JIT]: IFCC needs starting bracket at 4th argument. Please pass it and don't forget to close it.")
    end
  end
end

-- Function to split strings. Any questions?
function string:split( inSplitPattern, outResults )
  outResults = outResults or {}
  local theStart = 1
  local theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = self:find(inSplitPattern, theStart)
  while theSplitStart do
    table.insert( outResults, self:sub(theStart, theSplitStart-1) )
    theStart = theSplitEnd + 1
    theSplitStart, theSplitEnd = self:find(inSplitPattern, theStart)
  end
  table.insert( outResults, self:sub(theStart) )
  return outResults
end

-- I create new function to ensure that variables won't escape local context.
function main(filename,gencodeswitch)
  local file = io.open(filename, "r")
  if file == nil then
    --Oops, an error occured. Couldn't open file.
    print("[JIT]: Please pass valid filename.")
    os.exit() --Bye, see ya later
    return
  end
  --No error found while opening file

  local space,params,command,paramTable,paramAmount

  for line in file:lines() do
    --We need to parse this instruction.
    --So break it into main command and it's params.
    space = (line..' '):find(" ") --Find first space occurence (to divide command from it's arguments).
    params = line:sub(space+1) -- To get params just split string.
    command = line:sub(1, space-1) -- To get command without trailing space.
    --Actually, this space will get removed.

    paramTable = params:split(',')

    -- HACK: Looks like ineffective solution, but who cares?
    --for i = 1, #paramTable do paramAmount = paramAmount + 1 end
    paramAmount = #paramTable
    print ('--' .. line)
    parse(command,paramTable,paramAmount)
  end
  file:close()
  --Done parsing. Generate code
  if brackets ~= 0 then print("[JIT] Unbalanced brackets.") os.exit() end
  if gencodeswitch == "-gencode" then print(output) end
  --loadstring(output)()
end

if arg[1] == nil then
  --User didn't pass any arguments.
  print [[
Brainfuck# v 1.0
Usage:
.\lua start.lua <input> [-print]
Where:
.\lua - lua executable
start.lua - main module name
<input> - input filename (non-optional!)
[-print] - Optional, print source before execution.]]
  os.exit()
else
  --User passed an argument
  main(arg[1],arg[2])
end
```

Comment: So i am learning Lua actually and in C/C++ programming i have 4 year experience, but anyways your solution seems ok. Also remember that string concentration '..' needs to be separated from each other